# Can you force separate threads in Dart?

Tags: dart, reactive-streams

We have a flutter app that works well, but sometimes it freezes for a second or two while lots of computation is occurring.

We have a bunch of streams and listeners on the backend. Its highly reactive. Sometimes an event(s) will happen that causes many listeners to react at nearly the same time. When this happens the user cannot do anything on the front end until much of the computation has finished.

I'd like to fix this but I'm not sure how. One thing I do know is that several of our listeners (and the processes they initiate) don't really have to happen right away. I wish I could say this to some of our listeners (or, that is, specific streams), "Listen, if the computational load is heavy when you get triggered, just chill until it's low. You're not a high priority, you can wait." but I'm not familiar enough yet with dart to know how to achieve that.

Another solution I thought of was to have a dedicated thread for the front end, and force all backend computation to be contained within a separate thread. I don't think I have the option of forcing separate cores (parallelism), so maybe that wouldn't help. idk.

Can you point me in the right direction?

In the end I just want to be able to prioritize the front end above all else.

Comment: Are you familiar with isolates? https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#isolates

Comment: @mmcdon20 I was not familiar with the term, thank you, but I did know this is how dart basically works, "Each isolate has its own memory heap, ensuring that no isolate’s state is accessible from any other isolate." Hopefully this documentation will have the details I lack.

Comment: With isolates it is possible to offload some of the work from the main thread to a background thread. It is true that you cannot see the state of another isolate directly, but you can pass messages from one isolate to another.

Comment: @mmcdon20 I read that here, https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a "then you can use `Isolate.spawn()` or Flutter’s `compute()` function. Both of those functions create a separate isolate to do the number crunching, leaving your main isolate free" do you think using `isolate.spawn()` for the low priority processes (as in calling that inside the `.listen()` to trigger the rest of the process) would be the best way to go?

Comment: I think calling `compute()` will provide a more convenient API for responding to an event inside of a `listen()` call. I would suggest trying this first, since it will be easier to implement than going the `Isolate.spawn()` approach. And maybe it will be enough to solve your freezing issues. `Isolate.spawn()` will give you more flexibility, but it's definitely more complex.